# Esto soluciona el salto de línea ¿Habría otra forma de hacerlo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, vscode

Tengo un código que permite quitar el salto de línea de una string a otro por ejemplo:

Tenia un String así :

> "Nuestro sistema de dos" & vbCrLf & "cámaras más avanzado." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
> "Resistente de arriba abajo." & vbCrLf & "Y de un borde a otro." & vbCrLf & "Un chip superrápido" & vbCrLf & "que deja atrás" & vbCrLf & "a la competencia."

```
Dim str3 As String = ""

            For lPos As Integer = 0 To texto.Count - 1
                Dim letra As String = texto.Chars(lPos)
                'Si la posicion del texto es menor que el contenido de cantidad del texto -1 entonces
                If (lPos + 2) < texto.Count - 1 Then
                    'Si letra = vbCr y el caracter el texto(posicion+1) = vbLf y caracter del texto(posicion+2) = vbcr
                    If letra = vbCr And texto.Chars(lPos + 1) = vbLf And texto.Chars(lPos + 2) = vbCr Then
                        'posicion = posicion+1
                        lPos = lPos + 1
                    Else
                        'Concatena las letras
                        str3 = str3 + letra
                    End If
                Else
                    'Concatena las ultimas letras
                    str3 = str3 + letra
                End If

            Next

            Return str3
```

Con esto le había solucionado

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es la pregunta? replace no funciono?

Comment: no entiendo cual es la pregunta?

Comment: aclara bien el lenguaje de programacion, o es vb o c#

Answer (score 0):

Podrías remplazar los saltos de línea con el Objeto Strings y la función Replace , algo de hacer-lo así

```
Texto = Strings.Replace(Texto, vbCrLf , Space(1), -1, CompareMethod.Binary )
```